# Process.stderr value changes when node js process runs in background,its properties like columns and rows dont exist

Tags: node.js

Node js process.stderr >>>>>>>>>

if I run node js like this

```
{ domain: null,
_events: {},
_maxListeners: 10,
fd: 2,
writable: true,
readable: false,
autoClose: false,
_type: 'fs',
_isStdio: true,
destroySoon: [Function],
destroy: [Function] }

developers@workspace1/$ > node test.js > test.log 2>&1 &
```

Answer (score 0):

You have redirected stdout to a file with `> test.log`, and redirected stderr to stdout using `2>&1`. That means that `stderr` no longer points at a terminal at all, but at a file, and files do not have a number of columns.

Comment: But I want to run Node js in background ,And want same process.stderr value or similar streams which will match this value.

Comment: Then you'll need to pass in some arguments to specify the number of columns you want in the file or something. Why is the column number so important when outputting to the file? Usually things that depend heavily in terminal size don't conceptually make much sense when running in the background anyway.